# Get Related Category Product

Tags: php, mysql

I have two Table call **category table and product table**
and single product can have multiple categories for eg: 1,2,3,
in category page like to show all products related to categoryid

I wrote queries E.g (select * from producttable where categoryid = 1),
how would i match particular categoryid with ProductTable categoryid column ?

following are my table information

```
Category Table
id | categoryname 
1  | abc
2  | pqr
3  | xyz

product Table 
id | productname | categoryid
1  | abc         | 1,2,3
```

Comment: You wouldn't. See normalization

Comment: Internet search : 'mysql search comma separated value' returns useful links. However, please do as @Strawberry suggests, and restructure your tables, it will be a lot easier later.

Answer (score 0):

use like operator

```
SELECT * FROM product where categoryid LIKE '%1%';
```

or you can use regular expression in your sql.

Comment: if there was more than one value with a '1' in it, i.e. '21' or '213' etc. then your query would match. I suggest you need to include the ',' (comma) in the 'like' test somehow. It is really about matching exact values that are separated by a comma. Please specify the regular expression that should be used.